# How to export or diff files which are commited by a specific user with svn?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, diff

I need to check differences of the files which I committed before.
But if I try to diff or export files by using revision range option,
the files which others committed also shown in the result.

I need the only files which I committed.
How to export or diff files which are committed by a specific user with svn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save below python file as `userchanges.py` in current directory and make it executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from subprocess import call
data =  sys.stdin.readlines()
data = data[1:]
horiz_line = '-' * 72
data_len = len(data)
i = 0
while i < data_len:
  while data[i].strip() != horiz_line:
    i += 1
  i += 1
  if i >= data_len:
    break
  rev, name, rest = data[i].split(' | ', 2)
  if name == sys.argv[1]:
    i += 2
    while data[i].strip() != '':
      line = data[i].strip().split(' ')
      print("svn diff -r %s %s" % (rev, line[1][1:]))
      call("svn diff -r %s %s" % (rev, line[1][1:]), shell=True)
      i += 1
  i += 1
```

Then run:

```
svn checkout path/to/your/trunk
svn log -v trunk | ./userchanges.py youruser
```

where `youruser` is svn user name of the user you want to inspect.

It will run `svn diff` for each file and revision by selected user.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
i dont know phython at all but maybe i can translate the codes to other language i know.
i wish there was a easy command to do that on svn its self or tortoisesvn.